# How to register help/reset/settings Scorable (not proactive) in Azure Functions Bot?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-functions

There're multiple tutorials on how to implement global message handler that allows reacting on special words anywhere in one fashion without touching dialogs' code. For example, "start over" should result in full reset regardless of current position in conversation flow.

They're quite similar and consist of three easy steps:

1. Create a subclass of ScorableBase. (Done.)
2. "Wrap" it into Autofac Module. (Done.)
3. **Register the Module in Global.asax.cs**. (How in Azure Functions?)

I can't figure out how to make the last step in Azure Functions bot's code. [According to tutorials it should be done in this fashion:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs#register-the-module)

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        this.RegisterBotModules();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    private void RegisterBotModules()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());

        //Register the module within the Conversation container
        builder.RegisterModule<GlobalMessageHandlersBotModule>();

        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
    }
}
```

But Azure Functions bot has **run.csx** instead of **Global.asax.cs** and it doesn't utilize neither `HttpApplication` nor `ContainerBuilder` nor `GlobalConfuration`. And overall it has no even remotely similar code to the main initialization code of a Web App Bot.

How can I register the module from step 2 or otherwise implement "start over" feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can still be done in a Function. Since you do not have a global.asax file you have to do this:

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");

    // Initialize the azure bot
    using (BotService.Initialize())
    {

        var resolveAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(resolveAssembly));            
        builder.Register(c => new SettingsScorable(c.Resolve<IDialogTask>() ))
                       .As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>()
                       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);

...
...
    }
}
```

Then outside of this scope, you can declare your scorableBase and scorableDialog

```
public class SettingsDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        ...
    }

    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SettingsScorable : ScorableBase<IActivity, string, double>
{
    private readonly IDialogTask task;
    public SettingsScorable(IDialogTask task)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override async Task<string> PrepareAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override bool HasScore(IActivity item, string state)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override double GetScore(IActivity item, string state)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override Task DoneAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Meanwhile, I figured out a solution too. By combining them we get a more laconic code:

`Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder => builder.Register(c => new ResetScorableDialog(c.Resolve<IDialogTask>())).As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope());` What do you think?